# How to concatenate to form the table name from previous query in Oracle

Tags: oracle

From the following script I am getting the project_name which need to form the part of the table name in my next query, how to do this in oracle

Query1:

```
SELECT PROJECT FROM testServer_l WHERE liveConnection LIKE '%test01.azure.cloud%'
```

Output of the above query is: `91869 90237 87732 103868 96995 102646 98178 100587 99887 90277 68240 103630 92756 83169 90070 96194`

Query2:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T91869.TotalConnection
```

The table name is `'T'` + `'ProjectName'` [from the above query] for example `T+91869`

Comment: @joseph, you posted link to MS SQL Server problem. This is **Oracle** we're discussing here, so - no, I don't think that *this* answers the question.

Comment: [Concatenation Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Concatenation-Operator.html#GUID-08C10738-706B-4290-B7CD-C279EBC90F7E): `||`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd - as you said - *concatenate* `T` to `project`. Use

- `concat` function, e.g. `select concat('T', project)`

  - drawback: `concat` accepts only two parameters, so - if you have to concatenate more than two of them, you'll have to nest function calls
- double pipe `||` concatenation operator (as I did)

  - benefit: concatenate as many strings as you want

---

However, that's not enough in what you're doing - you'll need **dynamic SQL**.

Here's an example:

Sample *project* tables:

```
SQL> create table t91869 as select * from emp;

Table created.

SQL> create table t90237 as select * from dept;

Table created.
```

List of projects:

```
SQL> create table testserver_l as
  2    select 91869 project from dual union all
  3    select 90237         from dual;

Table created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select 'T' || project as project
  5                  from testserver_l
  6                 )
  7    loop
  8      execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || cur_r.project into l_cnt;
  9      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.project ||': '|| l_cnt);
 10    end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /
T91869: 14
T90237: 4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```